# I’m very confused on why the writer says that his definitions (inverse, composite, etc) would be true for any “set”…

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42MlF.jpg)

I’m very confused on why the writer says that his definitions (inverse, composite, etc) would be true for any “set”… as this would not be the case right? As only relations have a domain and range…

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What book is this from?   The sets that this page refers to are u,v pairs where u is related to v.

Comment: Endertons set theory is the book

Comment: Apparently the intent is "arbitrary sets _of pairs_". You're right that the sentence wasn't very precise.

Comment: That's interesting, you're on page 44 and it looks like someone was asking about page 46 a little earlier: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4657852/139123

Comment: Ohhh how did you find this out so I can be careful if it… sorry for the specific question but it’s kinda scary to think that wasn’t so clear

Comment: If the book defines these relations for a set, then not only relations can have a domain and range. You need to read the book as it is written, not based on what was written in someone else's book, especially in a case like this where it seems the only difference is that the definitions are extended here. (They apply to the old things in the old way, but also apply to some new things.)

Comment: Yeah actually that was me, I have two separate account and I keep forgetting not to post between them, my apologies. Also I am reading the book, but it’s quite difficult to adjust to his writing conversation..

Comment: "As only relations have a domain and range…" Not true. If $R$ is not a set of pairs, than condition $\exists y \langle x,y \rangle \in R$ (see page 40) is always false, and thus $x \in R$ is false also, that means that $\text {dom } R$ is empty.

Comment: That’s what I thought too. A set having a domain seems to disobey the definition of a domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider a concrete example.

Let F = ∅, so F is clearly not a relation.

Then

$F^{-1}$ = {<u,v> | <v,u> $\in$ ∅} = ∅

So we can consider inverses for any set, but if the set does not contain any ordered pairs, the inverse is just empty.

Similarly for the other definitions.